# Tensorflow: multiply matrix columns by elements of vector and get matrix back

Tags: tensorflow, vector, matrix-multiplication

Here is what I would like to accomplish in Tensorflow.

I have 2x2 matrix (trainable)

```
x_1 x_2
x_3 x_4
```

and I have input vector

```
a
b
```

I would like to multiply each column of matrix by element of vector and get back the following matrix

```
ax_1 bx_2
ax_3 bx_4
```

I can get this result by declaring each column of matrix as separate variable, but I wonder if there is more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html), you should be fine using the regular multiplication operator:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant([[3, 5], [7, 11]], dtype=tf.int32)
a = tf.constant([4, 8], dtype=tf.int32)
y = x * a

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(y))  # Result: [[12, 40], [28, 88]]
```